# How to extract index columns and rows in R?

Tags: r

I have a function that counts the occurrence of letters and characters for any script. However, I do not know how to extract the indexes of columns and rows for individual letters (characters) from a given script. Can you guide me and explain how to do it in a simple way?

As an example, I used a script called September, in which only the word September is stored.

My function:

```
fun <- function(filename)
{
  file <- paste(readLines(filename), collapse = '')
  chars <- strsplit(file, NULL)[[1]]
  summary(factor(chars))
}
source('September.r')
data.frame(fun('September.r'))
```

Result:

```
b 1
e 3
m 1
p 1
r 1
S 1
t 1
```

I would like to get something like that:

```
char count row col   
b    1     1   7
e    3     1   2,5,8
m    1     1   6
p    1     1   3
r    1     1   9
S    1     1   1
t    1     1   4
```

## Update

When I tested the @akrun code, I noticed that the program was working incorrectly for more text.

```
text <- "September,
September, September,
September, September"
```

As you can see from the example below, the program does not count column indexes. Because columns should be counted from 1 for each new line. The number of rows should not be set in advance. Can you help something?

## Example

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
    char Count   row                                                     col
   <chr> <int> <dbl>                                                   <chr>
 1           2     1                                                  22, 44
 2  "\n"     2     1                                                  11, 33
 3     ,     4     1                                          10, 21, 32, 43
 4     b     5     1                                       7, 18, 29, 40, 51
 5     e    15     1 2, 5, 8, 13, 16, 19, 24, 27, 30, 35, 38, 41, 46, 49, 52
 6     m     5     1                                       6, 17, 28, 39, 50
 7     p     5     1                                       3, 14, 25, 36, 47
 8     r     5     1                                       9, 20, 31, 42, 53
 9     S     5     1                                       1, 12, 23, 34, 45
10     t     5     1                                       4, 15, 26, 37, 48
```

Comment: Could you show a small reproducible example to arrive at the output

Comment: An example is my function, I mean how can I get indexes for columns and rows so that the function returns what is above.

Comment: I meant about the input data for your function.  Are you saying that others should construct the data by their own and test your function?

Comment: The function should work for every script my contains only the word "September". The function works well.

Comment: It is not entirely clear about how your data looks like `set.seed(24);
 m1 <- replicate(5, sample(c('S', 'e', 'p', 't', 'e', 'm', 'b', 'e', 'r'))); library(reshape2);library(dat.table);setDT(melt(m1))[, .(count = .N, col = paste(unique(Var2), collapse=', ')) , .(row = Var1, char = value)][order(row)]`  We are just asking for a small dataset to help us to help you and to avoid back and forth comments like `it is not how my data looks like`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 'text' is a string, then here is another option with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
str_split(text, "")[[1]] %>%
     tibble(char = .) %>% 
     rownames_to_column('rn') %>% 
     group_by(char) %>% 
     summarise(Count = n(), row = 1, col = toString(rn))
# A tibble: 7 x 4
#   char Count   row     col
#  <chr> <int> <dbl>   <chr>
#1     b     1     1       7
#2     e     3     1 2, 5, 8
#3     m     1     1       6
#4     p     1     1       3
#5     r     1     1       9
#6     S     1     1       1
#7     t     1     1       4
```

#### data

```
text <- "September"
```

Comment: I mean to create a function that will be based and a source with the file r, as in my original example.

Comment: @Kim  It will be just to add that  line above `function(file_path){
  text = paste(readLines(file_path), collapse = '');`

Comment: I still have a question, how can I set in the code to search for me, for example, only string c("S", "b")?

Comment: @Kim You can use `filter(char %in% c("S", "b"))` to get only those rows after `summarise` or before that

Comment: When testing your program I noticed that it does not work well, i.e. when you enter a longer text, the columns are not counted from the first in the following lines of text.

Comment: @Kim Could you update your post with a representative example that creates this problem

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

text = "September."

unique(unlist(strsplit(text, ""))) %>%
  sapply(gregexpr, text, fixed = TRUE) %>%
  unlist() %>%
  data.frame(letter = names(.), col = .) %>%
  group_by(letter = gsub("^(.).*", "\\1", letter)) %>%
  summarize(count = n(),
            col = paste(col, collapse = ","))
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 8 x 3
  letter count   col
   <chr> <int> <chr>
1      .     1    10
2      b     1     7
3      e     3 2,5,8
4      m     1     6
5      p     1     3
6      r     1     9
7      S     1     1
8      t     1     4
```

To modify it so that it is a function that takes a file connection instead, write the following:

```
char_ind_count = function(file_path){
  text = paste(readLines(file_path), collapse = '')

  unique(unlist(strsplit(text, ""))) %>%
    sapply(gregexpr, text, fixed = TRUE) %>%
    unlist() %>%
    data.frame(letter = names(.), col = .) %>%
    group_by(letter = gsub("^(.).*", "\\1", letter)) %>%
    summarize(count = n(),
              col = paste(col, collapse = ","))
}
```

Supply file path or use `textConnection` to supply strings:

```
char_ind_count("<path_to_file>/extract_index_cols.txt")
char_ind_count(textConnection(text1))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, and how can I make it work so that I can load any script?

Comment: @Kim It depends on what "script" you're trying to load. Are you loading in `.txt` file where each text file contains only the text you're trying to count the indices?

Comment: I thought about setting the source as any script

Comment: @Kim Can you be more specific? So you want it to be able to read _any_ file type? or just text files?

Comment: I mean to create a function that will be based and a source with the file r, as in my original example.

Comment: @Kim See my updates. I hope this is what you're looking for. If you're reading in an R script instead of a text file, just save the R script and supply the path to that script in the function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160351/discussion-between-kim-and-user).

Comment: When testing your program I noticed that it does not work well, i.e. when you enter a longer text, the columns are not counted from the first in the following lines of text.