# Counting letters in the text R

Tags: r

I have a program that counts letters and characters in the text, but it does not work correctly. As you can see from the example below, the program does not count column indexes. I do not know how to set the program after the last letter (character) in the line to go to the next line and count from 1. Can you help me? I have two different programs, one does not count rows.

## My codes:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
str_split(text, "")[[1]] %>%
  tibble(char = .) %>% 
  rownames_to_column('rn') %>% 
  group_by(char) %>% 
  summarise(Count = n(), row = 1, col = toString(rn))

unique(unlist(strsplit(text, ""))) %>%
  sapply(gregexpr, text, fixed = TRUE) %>%
  unlist() %>%
  data.frame(letter = names(.), col = .) %>%
  group_by(letter = gsub("^(.).*", "\\1", letter)) %>%
  summarize(count = n(),
            col = paste(col, collapse = ","))


text <- "Only two things are infinite, 
the universe and human stupidity, 
and I'm not sure about the former. (A. Einstein)"
```

## Results:

```
# A tibble: 31 x 4
    char Count   row                                                                    col
   <chr> <int> <dbl>                                                                  <chr>
 1     '     1     1                                                                     72
 2          18     1 5, 9, 16, 20, 30, 35, 44, 48, 54, 65, 70, 74, 78, 83, 89, 93, 101, 105
 3  "\n"     2     1                                                                 31, 66
 4     (     1     1                                                                    102
 5     )     1     1                                                                    114
 6     ,     2     1                                                                 29, 64
 7     .     2     1                                                               100, 104
 8     a     5     1                                                     17, 45, 52, 67, 84
 9     A     1     1                                                                    103
10     b     1     1                                                                     85
# ... with 21 more rows
```

Comment: intermediate results would be great (what are results of your script, what you would like to get) - this would make your question easier to read and understnad

Comment: I would like the program to recognize the lines so that the new line counts from 1 column.

Comment: _I have a program_. Don't forget to link to the question where you copied the codes from: [How to extract index columns and rows in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47599067/how-to-extract-index-columns-and-rows-in-r/47599359#47599359)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
library(stringi)

data.frame(Text=str_split(text, pattern = "\n")[[1]]) %>%
  group_by(n=row_number()) %>% 
  mutate(letters=sum(stri_count_fixed(tolower(Text), letters))) %>%
  mutate(marks=sum(stri_count_regex(tolower(Text), "[[:punct:]]"))) %>% 
  mutate(spaces=sum(stri_count_regex(tolower(Text),"[[:blank:]]"))) 
# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   n [3]
                                              Text     n letters marks spaces
                                            <fctr> <int>   <int> <int>  <int>
1                   Only two things are infinite,      1      24     1      5
2               the universe and human stupidity,      2      28     1      5
3 and I'm not sure about the former. (A. Einstein)     3      35     5      8
```

Comment: But your program does not count column indexes or rows.

Comment: @Elia rows are counted. See column `n`. What do you mean with column index? What would be the expected output in the above example?